# IMG dir can't be stored in db but viewed from the same variables used in query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I'm trying to upload an image to my server using the following form by Sanwebe.
[Can be found here](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-image-upload-and-resize-with-jquery-and-php).
However when I'm pressing upload, the new thumb loads perfectly fine. However, my image can't be uploaded to the database using the exact same variables from which the image is being viewed. How come?
I tried putting the `db` information just infront of the query. Like this:

```
echo '<div align="center">';
echo '<img src="images/profile-pictures/'.$thumb_prefix . $new_file_name.'" alt="Thumbnail">';
echo '</div>';

$profile_pic_temp = "../images/profile-pictures/" . $thumb_prefix . $new_file_name;
$profile_pic_full_temp = "../images/profile-pictures/" . $new_file_name;
$session_user = $_SESSION['user_confirm'];

require 'database.php';

$profile_pic_db_upload = $db->prepare("UPDATE login SET profile_picture_temp = :profile_pic_temp, profile_picture_full_temp = :profile_pic_full_temp WHERE user_session = :session_user");
$profile_pic_db_upload->bindParam(':session_user', $session_user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$profile_pic_db_upload->bindParam(':profile_pic_temp', $profile_picture_temp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$profile_pic_db_upload->bindParam(':profile_pic_full_temp', $profile_picture_full_temp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$profile_pic_db_upload->execute();
$confirm_upload_db = $profile_pic_db_upload->rowCount();

if($confirm_upload_db != 0){
    $popup_message = "Profile picture has been uploaded.";
    echo $popup_message;
}
else{
    $popup_message = "Profile picture could not be uploaded.";
    echo $popup_message;
}
```

**EDIT TWO:**
The query now runs, however, I get the feedback "Profile picture could not be uploaded.". How come the query does not run properly?

**EDIT FOUR:**
I have tried changing the `user_session = :session_user` to `id = 1` instead. I then get upload successfull, however, the value is only inserted into `profile_picture_temp` and is set to 0. Somehow the bindParam changes the value. Why?

**EDIT THREE:**
I have now tried using `mysqli` aswell. Same results here. Returning could not be uploaded. However, does not change value in DB.

```
$sql = "UPDATE login SET profile_picture_temp = ? AND profile_picture_full_temp = ? WHERE user_session = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or die ("Database error<br>" . $sql . "<br><b>Error message:</b> " . $mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $profile_picture_temp, $profile_picture_full_temp, $session_user);
$stmt->execute() or die("Something went wrong");
if($stmt->fetch()){
    $popup_message = "Profile picture has been uploaded.";
    echo $popup_message;
}
else{
    $popup_message = "Profile picture could not be uploaded.";
    echo $popup_message;
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Have you enabled [**ERRMODE::PDO_EXCEPTION** http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) so an exception will be thrown when a PDO error occurs?

Comment: @spencer7593 I have installed it now, and I get no errors. This is such a strange thing. Something is wrong with my query, however I can't see it.

Comment: @spencer7593 I get the following error if I put the echoing of the div's BENEATH the query. `x.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery.min.js:6x.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:6g @ jquery.form.min.js:7a.fn.ajaxSubmit @ jquery.form.min.js:7(anonymous function) @ scripts.js:30x.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:5x.event.add.v.handle @ jquery.min.js:5`

Comment: Is the InnoDB transaction being committed before you close the connection, or is it being rolled back? You might want to consider temporarily enabling the general_log in MySQL, and see what shows up there when you run a test, see if you're seeing the `UPDATE` statement in the log.

Comment: @spencer7593 I'm not the superuser on my server :S Using hosting. So I can get the general_log :(

Comment: I'm kind of stumped... Just to confirm, this code is in a php code block, being executed in the php file. If the `echo` is in the same php code block, and the echo is writing to the page.  Is `$db` variable in scope, is it a valid PDO connection object, connected to the database, in the correct database. For debugging, add a `var_dump $db;` before you reference it. (You do have PHP error reporting enabled, correct?) If `$db` is a valid PDO connection, with ERRMODE::PDO_EXCEPTION set, it should be throwing an exception is there is a database error.

Comment: @spencer7593 I have all error reporting enabled yes. I've tried debugging yes. Take a look on the edit. I managed to summon a new error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79201/discussion-between-gjert-i-gjersund-and-spencer7593).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The problem was fixed using the following query:**

```
$profile_picture_temp = "../images/profile-pictures/" . $thumb_prefix . $new_file_name;
$profile_picture_full_temp = "../images/profile-pictures/" . $new_file_name;
$session_user = $_SESSION['user_confirm'];

$sql = "UPDATE login l SET l.profile_picture_temp = ?, l.profile_picture_full_temp = ? WHERE l.user_session = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or die ("Database error<br>" . $sql . "<br><b>Error message:</b> " . $mysqli->error);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $profile_picture_temp, $profile_picture_full_temp, $session_user);
$stmt->execute() or die("Something went wrong");

$result = $stmt->affected_rows;
if($result == 1){
    $popup_message = "Profile picture has been uploaded.";
    echo $popup_message;
}
else{
    $popup_message = "Profile picture could not be uploaded.";
echo $popup_message;
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

I can't identify the problem itself, however, I managed to fix it by adding `UPDATE login l`. Using alias fixed it somehow.

Answer (score 10):

Are you sure this line isn't throwing a PHP error...

```
$confirm_upload_db = $$profile_pic_db_upload->rowCount();
                     ^^
```

The `$$` (two dollar signs) are how we reference a variable variable; but `$profile_pic_db_upload` doesn't contain the name of another variable, it's a reference to a PDO statement object.

Another note. The `rowCount()` function returns the number of rows affected by the `UPDATE` statement; if the UPDATE statement succeeds, but no actual changes are made to the row (because the values assigned to the columns are the same as what's already stored in the columns), then `rowCount()` will return 0.

(To change that behavior, to have it return the number of matched rows, you can use `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS`).

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of this. Now the query runs, however, I get the message: Profile picture could not be uploaded. And the DB has not been updated. How come?

Comment: The most likely reason for that is that `rowCount()` is returning 0. Likely because the update succeeded, but because no actual change was made to the row, because the values already stored in the row matched the values being assigned.

Comment: However, they are not the same. The values aren't being updated. This is the current: `../images/blankprofilepic.png`. What I want has URL: `../images/profile-pictures/thumb_SOMETHING`